# Reference or shared_ptr as member for association

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class *Bar*. *Bar* needs to access an other class *Foo* to be useful. 
So the instance of *Foo* has to outlive the instance of *Bar* using it.

I can't decide between two ways to write this. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> 
using namespace std; 

struct Foo {
    Foo(int _x) : x_(_x) {}
    ~Foo() {}
    int x_; 
}; 

struct Bar1 {  
    Bar1(Foo& _foo) : foo_(_foo) {}
    void print_foo() {cout << foo_.x_ << endl;}
private: 
    Foo& foo_; 
};

struct Bar2 {  
    Bar2(shared_ptr<Foo> _foo) : foo_{move(_foo)} {}
    void print_foo() {cout << foo_->x_ << std::endl;}
private:
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo_;
};

int main() 
{
    Foo f1{1}; 
    shared_ptr<Foo> f2 = make_shared<Foo>(2);
    Bar1 b1(f1); 
    b1.print_foo();
    Bar2 b2(f2); 
    b2.print_foo();
    return 0; 
}
```

I think, that *Bar1* gives the user more freedom on how to manage the lifetime of *Foo*
and it probably is more efficient. But it goes in an undefined (not sure if
this is the right word here) state, when the instance of *Foo* to which *foo_* refers is destroyed.

What is the preferred way to handle a situation like this and why?

Comment: why not create Foo in Bar constructor? do you need Foo to be passed to Bar?

Comment: If you want the users to be free to manage `Foo` in any way they want, than have them supply a callback for getting a valid `Foo` instance. Regardless, it's not *bad* to force users to manage `Foo` in a certain way, as long as you don't impose too much complexity unto their code. A `shared_ptr` is pretty good for that purpose.

Comment: @piotruś One instance of Foo can be used by multiple instances of Foo. So it can't de a member of Bar.

Comment: you didn't mentioned this, now it is clear you have to pass Foo to Bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the preferred way to handle this situation depends on the specifics of the situation.  As you identified, `Bar1` gives the user more freedom with the lifetime of `Foo`, and is more dangerous.  It is also more efficient (slightly), but probably not enough to be a concern.

If you know for a fact (and/or can prove) that `Foo` will always outlive all of your `Bar` objects (maybe you allocate the `Foo` you use on the stack in `main`), there is no problem using `Bar1`.  If you are unsure, `Bar2` would be the way to go.  Though the semantics may be wrong with `Bar2` (maybe you don't want `Bar` to keep your `Foo` alive).

This leads us to a third option: `weak_ptr`.  This would give the user control of the lifetime of `Foo`, but still allow `Bar` to have defined behavior when the `Foo` is destroyed.

```
struct Bar3 {
    Bar3(std::weak_ptr<Foo> _foo) : foo_(_foo) {}
    void print_foo_v1() {
        // throws if foo_'s object has been destroyed
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(foo_);
        std::cout << foo->x_ << std::endl;
    }
    void print_foo_v2() {
        // returns nullptr if foo_'s object has been destroyed
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(foo_.lock());
        if (foo) {
            std::cout << foo->x_ << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> foo_;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `Foo` will outlive `Bar` use reference-based solution because of simplicity and because it expresses what you want to achieve - that Bar references Foo. If you use pointers then the intent is not that clear.